# Is calling a mapper inside a model an OK?

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

Im on a learning curve of domain modeling and mappers.
Is it ok to call another mapper inside a model? For example:

```
class model_project extends model {
  [...]
  public function addTag($tag)
  {
   $tagMapper = new Mapper_Tag;
   $tag = $tagMapper->findByName($tag);
   if(!$tag) {
     // create new $tag
     $tagMapper->save($tag);
   }
  }
  [...]
}
```

I mean, is it ok to call some save function on mapper to get some login working on model or is it forbidden by a good pratice?

Comment: You're mean? I don't like mean people... (jk)

Answer (score 3):

A domain model shnould not know about other infrastructure like mapper. Teh domain model are simply objects which are modelling the domain. THose objects are created by a Factory or restored by a Repository, both outside the domain.

The domain model shouldn't care about saving or other things which makes no sense in that Bounded Context where it belongs.